# In my application I assigned value to textbox control at runtime but when I am trying to get value from textbox it shows null

Tags: java, selenium-rc

In my application I assigned value to textbox control at runtime but when I am trying to get value from textbox it shows null
and giving following error message

> **ERROR: This element has no value; is it really a form field?**

I tried following statement to get the value entered in text box.

```
String listname = selenium.getValue("//*[@id='div-entity-lists']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/p[1]/a[2]");
```

(not sure application may be developed in Ajax)

Comment: Since you are trying to read from <a> tag, I think it should be getText() rather than getValue()